# Calling nested model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested model

```
resources :customers do 
 resources :readings
end
```

I would like to now access my ../customerid/readings/new view from the show view of a customer.

How can I call the new readings view using a button when in the customers show view?

Customer's show.html

```
<%- model_class = Customer -%>
<div class="page-header">
<h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>
</div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.name %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:customer_currency) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.customer_currency %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:payment_terms) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.payment_terms %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:phase_type) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.phase_type %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:billing_address) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.billing_address %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:first_name) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.first_name %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:last_name) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.last_name %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:mobile) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.mobile %></dd>
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:email) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @customer.email %></dd>
</dl>


<div class="form-actions">
<%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")),
          customers_path, :class => 'btn'  %>
<%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
          edit_customer_path(@customer), :class => 'btn' %>


<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
          customer_path(@customer),
          :method => 'delete',
          :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm",   :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
          :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ["2.7 Nested Resources" Chapter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) of Ruby on Rails Guide on Routing, to get the following URL `/customers/:customer_id/readings/new`, use this:

```
customer_readings_path(@customer) # Generate the path for new Reading which belongs to @customer
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in time

```
  <%= link_to 'Readings', customer_readings_path(@customer) %> |
```